# How to get each day time in and out and count it in query between date range?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query i'm using right now:

```
Select *
from attendance
where (in_time BETWEEN '2019-06-20 00:00:01' and '2019-06-20 23:59:59')
and (out_time BETWEEN '2019-06-28 00:00:01' and '2019-06-28 23:59:59')
```

[image: Sample Database Image]

and i need an a output like this.

[image: Sample Output]

or any ideas how do i count each date range base on my sample database

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: @CalebGoodman I'm having a problem how do i input the exact date and count all the data with that day example for this is that the 2nd picture, i don't know how do i put that in my list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this query to collect data in_time and count then remove the time using substring.
`SELECT substring(in_time,1,10), COUNT(DISTINCT employees_id) 
FROM attendance 
WHERE (in_time BETWEEN '2019-06-20 00:00:01' and '2019-06-28 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY substring(in_time ,1,10)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to start with a list of dates and then use `left join` or a correlated subquery:

```
select d.dte,
       (select count(*)
        from attendance a
        where a.in_time <= dte and a.out_time >= dte
       ) as cnt
from (select date('2019-06-20') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-21') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-22') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-23') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-24') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-25') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-26') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-27') as dte union all
      select date('2019-06-28') as dte
     ) d;
```